# in bash split a variable into an array with each array value containing n values from the list

Tags: bash

So i'm issuing a query to mysql and it's returning say 1,000 rows,but each iteration of the program could return a different number of rows. I need to break up (without using a mysql limit) this result set into chunks of 100 rows that i can then programatically iterate through in these 100 row chunks.

So

```
MySQLOutPut='1 2 3 4 ... 10,000"
```

I need to turn that into an array that looks like

```
array[1]="1 2 3 ... 100"
array[2]="101 102 103 ... 200"
```

etc.

I have no clue how to accomplish this elegantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
# generate content
MySQLOutput=$(seq 1 10000 | tr '\n' ' ') # seq is awful, don't use in real life

# split into a large array, each item stored individually
read -r -a MySQLoutArr <<<"$MySQLOutput"

# add each batch of 100 items into a new array entry
batchSize=100
MySQLoutSplit=( )
for ((i=0; i<${#MySQLoutArr[@]}; i+=batchSize)); do
  MySQLoutSplit+=( "${MySQLoutArr[*]:i:batchSize}" )
done
```

To explain some of the finer points:

- `read -r -a foo` reads contents into an array named `foo`, split on IFS, up to the next character specified by `read -d` (none given here, thus reading only a single line). If you wanted each line to be a new array entry, consider `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a foo`, which will read each line into an array, terminated at the first NUL in the input stream.
- `"${foo[*]:i:batchSize}"` expands to a list of items in array `foo`, starting at index `i`, and taking the next `batchSize` items, concatenated into a single string with the first character in `$IFS` used as a separator.

Answer (score 2):

Using Charles' data generation:

```
MySQLOutput=$(seq 1 10000 | tr '\n' ' ')

# the sed command will add a newline after every 100 words
# and the mapfile command will read the lines into an array
mapfile -t MySQLOutSplit < <(
    sed -r 's/([^[:blank:]]+ ){100}/&\n/g; $s/\n$//' <<< "$MySQLOutput"
)

echo "${#MySQLOutSplit[@]}"
# 100

echo "${MySQLOutSplit[0]}"
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 

echo "${MySQLOutSplit[99]}"
# 9901 9902 9903 9904 9905 9906 9907 9908 9909 9910 9911 9912 9913 9914 9915 9916 9917 9918 9919 9920 9921 9922 9923 9924 9925 9926 9927 9928 9929 9930 9931 9932 9933 9934 9935 9936 9937 9938 9939 9940 9941 9942 9943 9944 9945 9946 9947 9948 9949 9950 9951 9952 9953 9954 9955 9956 9957 9958 9959 9960 9961 9962 9963 9964 9965 9966 9967 9968 9969 9970 9971 9972 9973 9974 9975 9976 9977 9978 9979 9980 9981 9982 9983 9984 9985 9986 9987 9988 9989 9990 9991 9992 9993 9994 9995 9996 9997 9998 9999 10000
```